# Why is this regex throwing a 'PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR' error?

Tags: php, regex

In the example at [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php), it says that the regular expression `/(?:\D+|<\d+>)*[!?]/` matched against `foobar foobar foobar` throws a `PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR` error. Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 5):

[Catastrophic Backtracking.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Incorrect nesting.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good link. Can you tell me what is meant by the sentence **The group has one iteration it can backtrack into.** in the 2nd line of the 3rd paragraph?